# Error : Multilingual App Toolkit build completed with errors

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a working project and it was working quite fine.
All of a sudden I am not able to build my Windows Phone project.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: win-ladenzeile, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Multilingual App Toolkit build started.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\Microsoft.Multilingual.WindowsPhone.targets(9,5): error : The file exists.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\Microsoft.Multilingual.WindowsPhone.targets(9,5): error : 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\Microsoft.Multilingual.WindowsPhone.targets(9,5): error : Update XLIFF build failed.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\Microsoft.Multilingual.WindowsPhone.targets(9,5): error : Multilingual App Toolkit build completed with errors.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried the following:

1. Disable and re-enable the Multilingual App Toolkit.
2. Repair the Multilingual App Toolkit.
3. Reinstall the Multilingual App Toolkit
4. `git reset head --hard`
5. Restart PC couple of times.

I am really confused and can't believe the Visual Studio suddenly started acting weird.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT - (After 18 hours)**

I am quite sure this has to do with the Multilingual App Toolkit.

I disabled it in the .csproj file

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\Microsoft.Multilingual.WindowsPhone.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Multilingual App Toolkit\Microsoft.Multilingual.WindowsPhone.targets')" Label="MultilingualAppToolkitForWindowsPhone" />
```

Also disabled "Enable Code Analysis on Build" as I was getting some errors about Code Analysis.

I hope the next version of the toolkit will fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this when you hit the max number of temp files on your system.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName);k(GetTempFileName);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

The Multilingual App Toolkit also uses this API and if you are already close to the limit, it can trigger the error.

To resolve this issues, please be sure to clean your %temp% folder to get unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem today and it seemed to be because the xlf files used by the Multiligual App Toolkit were not checked out of source control.

The actual problem appears to be the fact that the files are readonly on disk.